# Python. smtp with socks

Tags: python, smtp, socks

Anybody know free module like smtplib, but with socks or http proxy?

Comment: This can have the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397024/mail-client-in-python-using-sockets-onlyno-smtplib

Comment: This workaround in the bug might solve the problem for you: https://bugs.python.org/issue29687